# Does Azure AD support multi tenant user management with custom roles that can be mapped to custom permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Does Azure AD support multi tenant user management with custom roles? Custom roles refers to roles defined for the web application that is hosted in cloud. Also custom permissions / entitlements need to be defined that can be mapped to the custom roles.

ORG
--roles
--entitlements
--users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AAD supports it, but not fully.

We can [define the App roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-roles-for-an-application) in the app registration in the main tenant. Then [Assign users and groups to the app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).

After that, when a user which has been assigned an app role signs into your application, The app role you defined before will exist in its id token. You can parse it in your code to get the role.

But AAD doesn't support custom permissions / entitlements. You should implement this part in your own way. For example, you can set up a matching list of app roles and custom permissions in a configuration file. After you get the app role, find its matching custom permissions in the config file.

For how to make multi tenant user use this custom role, you just need to use [admin consent url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) to add this app registration into customer's tenant.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of customer's tenant}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

Sign in with an admin account of customer's tenant and do the admin consent for that tenant. Then an enterprise app will exist in that tenant. Now you can directly [Assign users and groups to the app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles). In this way, users from customer's tenant can use the app role.

Comment: so if entitlements are stored and managed in each application, and if an app is provided to map the roles (in Azure AD) and entitlements in each application - this can be resolved?

Comment: @user3760894 I think so. There should be many ways to do the match.